# node_modules in AngularJS 2 [ng cli] without System.config

Tags: angular, webpack, systemjs, node-modules, angular2-cli

How do I include `node_modules` without `System.config` with AngularJS 2 projects generated with `ng`?

Attempts (in `src/index.html`):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
```

Project setup:

```
npm install -g angular2-cli
ng init
npm install
npm install --save bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.5
npm start
```

Note: [by default] there is neither `systemjs.config.js` nor any reference to `System.config` in the file-tree anymore…

EDIT: Would be great if all my included node_modules are also pushed into the one bundle (e.g.: from `ng build -prod`).

Comment: From their [README on github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli): "We changed the build system between beta.10 and beta.14, from SystemJS to Webpack" - it looks like this question needs to be re-tagged..

Comment: Done. Retagged, including [tag:systemjs] still though because it is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include node_module assets such as css with your build, you need to list it in `angular-cli.json` like this:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Also checkout [Global Library Installation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation) from the angular-cli readme.

When you run `ng build -prod` the cli will bundle the listed files.

Comment: +1 & accepted: perfect, that worked. BTW: I did try something similar earlier today, but I think I only tried `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css`